# How to use scipy optimize.minimize function to compile keras sequential model using conjugate gradients?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, scipy

In

```
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=minimize(method='CG',fun=keras.losses.mean_squared_error(train_label,model.predict_classes(train_X)),x0=x0), metrics=['accuracy'])

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 14, in mean_squared_error
return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (67,) (67,2)
```

I am unable to figure out why the error is occurring
 In other case I have tried passing the original classes without converting it to one-hot variable then the following error occurred

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

Please help me in resolving this issue

```
train_X,valid_X,train_label,valid_label = train_test_split(train_X,Y_train_one_hot, test_size=0, random_state=42)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(22, kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',input_shape=(6,4,1),activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D((1, 1),padding='same',strides=(1,1)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(14, activation='sigmoid'))   

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=minimize(method='CG',fun=keras.losses.mean_squared_error(train_label,model.predict_classes(train_X)),x0=x0), metrics=['accuracy'])

history =model.fit(train_X, train_label,batch_size=batchsize,callbacks=callbacks,epochs=epochs,verbose=1,validation_data=(valid_X, valid_label))
```

Comment: Are you looking for code review or are you experiencing a bug or having trouble implementing something? If code review, this is not the right forum. If having trouble, please be specific what trouble you are experiencing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have edited the question for the specific error encountered during compilation

Comment: I am wondering to know if you were able to use scipy optimizer in model.compile in Keras, since you need to give training set in the fun; fun=keras.losses.mean_squared_error(train_label,model.predict_classes(train_X)). We often give the training and validation sets in model.fit